# Ctrl+A in rigging?

Tags: rigging

I am currently in pose mode trying to fix an issue, but something just made me curious: What does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> do in pose mode? I have the following screenshot:

[image: Ctrl+A]

What does each of these options do? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I mainly want to know what the second one does, I sort of know what the first one does but im not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option will apply the current transformations **after** all constraints have acted upon the bone (ie IK constraint, limit rotations, track to, etc). This can be a way of "applying" bone constraints.

I'm fairly certain the bone will remain as is until you move keyframes or refresh the screen. If you apply the keyframe the constraints probably will reactivate so it may produce undesired behaviour.